# Create one list with strings using read text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a jumble game in python that uses words from a text file rather than from words written directly into the python file(in this case the code works perfectly). But when I want to import them, I get this list:

```
[['amazement', ' awe', ' bombshell', ' curiosity', ' incredulity', '\r\n'], ['godsend', ' marvel', ' portent', ' prodigy', ' revelation', '\r\n'], ['stupefaction', ' unforeseen', ' wonder', ' shock', ' rarity', '\r\n'], ['miracle', ' abruptness', ' astonishment\r\n']]
```

I want words to be sorted in one single list, for example:

```
["amazement", "awe", "bombshell"...]
```

This is my python code:

```
import random

#Welcome the player
print("""
    Welcome to Word Jumble.
        Unscramble the letters to make a word.
""")


filename = "words/amazement_words.txt"

lst = []
with open(filename) as afile:
    for i in afile:
        i=i.split(",")
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)

word = random.choice(lst)
theWord = word

jumble = ""
while(len(word)>0):
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble+=word[position]
    word=word[:position]+word[position+1:]
print("The jumble word is: {}".format(jumble))

#Getting player's guess
guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

#congratulate the player
if(guess==theWord):
    print("Congratulations! You guessed it")
else:
    print ("Sorry, wrong guess.")

input("Thanks for playing. Press the enter key to exit.")
```

I have a text file with words:

```
    amazement, awe, bombshell, curiosity, incredulity,
    godsend, marvel, portent, prodigy, revelation,
    stupefaction, unforeseen, wonder, shock, rarity,
    miracle, abruptness, astonishment
```

Thank you for help and any suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

quasi one-liner does it:

```
with open("list_of_words.txt") as f:
    the_list = sorted(word.strip(",") for line in f for word in line.split())

print(the_list)
```

- use a double `for` in a gen-comprehension
- splitting against spaces is the trick: it gets rid of the line-termination chars and multiple spaces. Then, just get rid of the commas using `strip()`.
- Apply `sorted` on the resulting generator comprehension

result:

```
['abruptness', 'amazement', 'astonishment', 'awe', 'bombshell', 'curiosity', 'godsend', 'incredulity', 'marvel', 'miracle', 'portent', 'prodigy', 'rarity', 'revelation', 'shock', 'stupefaction', 'unforeseen', 'wonder']
```

Only drawback of this quick method is that if 2 words are only separated by a comma, it will issue the 2 words as-is.

In that latter case, just add a `for` in the gencomp like this to perform a split according to comma and drop the empty result string (`if word`):

```
with open("list_of_words.txt") as f:
    the_list = sorted(word for line in f for word_commas in line.split() for word in word_commas.split(",") if word)

print(the_list)
```

or in that latter case, maybe using regex split is better (we need to discard empty strings as well). Split expression being blank(s) or comma.

```
import re

with open("list_of_words.txt") as f:
    the_list = sorted(word for line in f for word in re.split(r"\s+|,",line) if word)
```

Comment: the one-liner did the trick! Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation.

Comment: @JureŠtabuc and Jean-François Fabre♦, is there a way to split for either '.' or '?' such that sentences ending in question mark also are split

Comment: yes, using regular expression split, like in my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302595/6451573

Answer (score 1):

use

```
lst.extend(i)
```

instead of

```
lst.append(i)
```

split return a list and you append a list to list everytime. Using extend instead will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
import random

#Welcome the player
print("""
    Welcome to Word Jumble.
        Unscramble the letters to make a word.
""")

name = "   My name   "

filename = "words/amazement_words.txt"

lst = []
file = open(filename, 'r')
data = file.readlines()

another_lst = []
for line in data:
    lst.append(line.strip().split(','))
print(lst)
for line in lst:
    for li in line:
        another_lst.append(li.strip())

print()
print()
print(another_lst)

word = random.choice(lst)
theWord = word

jumble = ""
while(len(word)>0):
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble+=word[position]
    word=word[:position]+word[position+1:]
print("The jumble word is: {}".format(jumble))

#Getting player's guess
guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

#congratulate the player
if(guess==theWord):
    print("Congratulations! You guessed it")
else:
    print ("Sorry, wrong guess.")

input("Thanks for playing. Press the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 0):

str.split() generates a list, so if you append it to your result you get a list of lists. 
A solution would be to concatenate the 2 list (+)

You can get rid of the '\r\n' by stripping i before splitting it