# Check for (whole only) words in string

Tags: python, string, count, find

Training on Checkio. The task is called Popular words. The task is to search for words from a list (of strings) in a given string.

For example:

```
textt="When I was One I had just begun When I was Two I was nearly new"

wwords=['i', 'was', 'three', 'near']
```

My code goes like:

```
def popular_words(text: str, words: list) -> dict:
    # your code here

    occurence={}
    text=text.lower()


    for i in words:
        occurence[i]=(text.count(i))

    # incorrectly takes "nearly" as "near"


    print(occurence)
    return(occurence)

popular_words(textt,wwords)
```

which works almost fine, returning

```
{'i': 4, 'was': 3, 'three': 0, 'near': 1}
```

thus counting "near" as a part of the "nearly". It was obviously the authors intention. I, however, cannot find a way to get aroud this other than

```
"search for words that are not first (index 0) or last (last index) and for these that begin/end with whitespace"
```

May I ask for a help, please? Building upon this rather childish code, please.

Comment: Hey what do you want your code to do? Do you want it to count the number of occurrence of word?

Comment: The task is to return a dictionary with the words as keys and the occurences as values. Just as it does now. Only ignoring the words inside words. It is written in the question.

Comment: It's worth noting that the collections module has a built in counter class: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Suggest you read [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'd be better off *splitting* your sentence, then count the words, not the substrings:

```
textt="When I was One I had just begun When I was Two I was nearly new"
wwords=['i', 'was', 'three', 'near']
text_words = textt.lower().split()
result = {w:text_words.count(w) for w in wwords}

print(result)
```

prints:

```
{'three': 0, 'i': 4, 'near': 0, 'was': 3}
```

if the text has punctuation now, you're better off with regular expressions to split the string according to non-alphanum:

```
import re

textt="When I was One, I had just begun.I was Two when I was nearly new"

wwords=['i', 'was', 'three', 'near']
text_words = re.split("\W+",textt.lower())
result = {w:text_words.count(w) for w in wwords}
```

result:

```
{'was': 3, 'near': 0, 'three': 0, 'i': 4}
```

(another alternative is to use `findall` on word characters: `text_words = re.findall(r"\w+",textt.lower())`)

Now if your list of "important" words is big, maybe it's better to count *all* the words, and filter afterwards, using the classical `collections.Counter`:

```
text_words = collections.Counter(re.split("\W+",textt.lower()))
result = {w:text_words.get(w) for w in wwords}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have come to that myself. Works nice (up no now when the tutorial gave me a word containing an apostrophe that doesnt get counted correctly which I will, however, solve in the morning). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your simple solution would be this one:

```
from collections import Counter

textt="When I was One I had just begun When I was Two I was nearly new".lower()
wwords=['i', 'was', 'three', 'near']

txt = textt.split()

keys = Counter(txt)

for i in wwords:
    print(i + ' : ' + str(keys[i]))
```